# Returning data from looped nested AJAX queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a nested set of ajax calls, something like:

```js
function getSubcategories(cat,callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url:'myurl.php',
    data:'q='+cat,
    dataType='json',
    success:function(result){ callback(result) }
  });
}

function getSubcatElements(subcat,callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url:'myurl2.php',
    data:'q='+subcat,
    dataType='json',
    success:function(result){ callback(result) }
  });
}  

function organizeData(cat,callback) {
getSubcategories(cat,function(res){
  totals=0;
  list=new Array;
  $.each(res['subcat'],function(key,val){
    getSubcatElements(val,function(items){
      $.each(items['collection'],function(key2,val2) {
        list.push(val2['descriptor']);
      });
      totals+=items['count'];
      // If I shove "totals" and "list" into an object here to callback, obviously gets called many times
    }
    // If I return an object here, it doesn't actually have counts from the asynchronous call above
  }

function doStuff(cat) {
  organizeData(cat,function() {
    //stuff
  });
```

So I'm running a looped asynchronous query that's a child of another asynch query, and I want the final result of the child loop without being "lazy". Right now I have it just returning updated results so the numbers change a few times, but I'd like to do it in one fell swoop.

It seems that the obvious place to do it would be to store the results in the asynch and return it after the `$.each()`, but JavaScript is insane and scoffs at things like obviousness. I feel like this should involve `$.Deferred()` but the samples I found all seemed like they should trigger after the first iteration ...

(The functions are deliberately separated as there is sometimes reason to use only one or only the other).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: correction in your code, not  an answer.  data:'q=cat', should be  data:'q='+cat,   and data:'q=subcat', should be data:'q='+subcat,  since you are passing into function as value.

Comment: Ah, you're right, it's correct in the real code -- I just transcribed it incorrectly when simplifying it. (it also has more arguments, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, your approach is fine. I want to add following changes in your code

```
function organizeData(cat, callback) {
    getSubcategories(cat, function(res) {
        totals = 0;
        list = new Array();
        totalSubCatItem = res['subcat'].length;
        currentSubCatItem = 0;
        $.each(res['subcat'], function(key, val) {
            getSubcatElements(val, function(items) {
                $.each(items['collection'], function(key2, val2) {
                    list.push(val2['descriptor']);
                });
                totals += items['count'];
                // If I shove "totals" and "list" into an object here to callback, obviously gets called many times
                // Here the solution
                currentSubCatItem++;
                if(currentSubCatItem === totalSubCatItem){
                    callback(/** pass argument here **/)
                }           

            });
            // If I return an object here, it doesn't actually have counts from the asynchronous call above
        });
    })
}

function doStuff(cat) {
    organizeData(cat, function( result) {
        //stuff
        console.log(result)
    });
}
```

Comment: That is blindingly obvious. Simply don't call the callback until it's done by watching the count, duh. I attribute lack of sleep. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should probably organize your database query on the server side so it's returning a single, multi-plexed result. Rather than calling it lots of times.

Barring that, and assuming you don't know how many sub-categories you're going to call until your category call returns, your best bet is to create a global var that counts up every time it makes a call, and then counts down every time the callback receives a result. Whenever callback fires, counts down, and the new count is zero, do your updates.

Comment: Valid, but this is still a project with many moving targets -- enough so that I've forsaken such things for now since half the time the effort that went in to allow it is for naught. Those sorts of optimizations are decidedly waiting on feature stabilization, but thanks :-)